# Woocommerce change Attribute when empty

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, hook

I do have that code in my functions.php for my Product Overview Site:

```
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'wotom_show_attributes_title', 15);

function wotom_show_attributes_title()
{
 global $product;

    $ab1 = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weingut');
    $ab2 = $product->get_attribute ('pa_rebsorte');
    $ab3 = $product->get_attribute ('pa_dac-lage');
    $ab4 = $product->get_attribute ('pa_jahrgang');
    $ab5 = $product->get_attribute ('pa_region');



    echo "<h1 class='shoppage_header1'>" . __($ab1,'woocommerce') . "</h1>";
    echo "<h1 class='shoppage_header2'>" . __($ab2,'woocommerce') . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2 class='shoppage_sub1'>" . __($ab3,'woocommerce') . "</h2>";
    echo ($ab5) ? "<h2 class='shoppage_sub2'>" . __($ab4,'woocommerce') . "</h2>" : "";



}
```

Updated code! 
but the `echo($ab5) ? ...` isnt working.

Comment: You introduce another variable which you declare with $ab3 or $ab5, if $ab3 is empty. This new variable you use in the echo instead of $ab3.

Comment: Do a checking before `echo` like `echo ( $ab1 ) ? "<h1 class='shoppage_header1'>" . __($ab1,'woocommerce') . "</h1>" : "";`

Comment: Ive declared a new variable: `$ab5 = $product->get_attribute ('pa_region');` and added this to the code: `echo ($ab5) ? "<h2 class='shoppage_sub2'>" . __($ab4,'woocommerce') . "</h2>" : "";` but no changes took effekt. the Code in the question has been updated @itzmekhokan